# velodyne VLP-32

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I m having some troubles trying to write a launch file specific to the new velodyne VLP-32C. Thank you in advence

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278330/velodyne-vlp-32/) by [ixorim](https://answers.ros.org/users/33058/ixorim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-12-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-29**:
Welcome! What package are you using?

**Comment by [ixorim](https://answers.ros.org/users/33058/ixorim/) on 2017-12-29**:
ros-kinetic-velodyne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you take a look at the [velodyne tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20HDL-32E#View_Data) you'll see that there's already a launch file that you can use. Just run

```
roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud 32e_points.launch calibration:=/home/user/32db.yaml
```

**Note:** set the `calibration` parameter to whatever your calibration file is.

---

**Update:**

It looks like it may not be [supported](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_driver#Supported_Devices):

> This driver supports all current Velodyne HDL-64E, HDL-32E and VLP-16 models.

but the wiki says nothing about the 32C. Maybe you should file an [issue](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ixorim](https://answers.ros.org/users/33058/ixorim/) on 2017-12-29**:
yes I have done that but it's for HDL-32E module. I have got the calibration file in the flash drive and everything but need to create a new launch file for the VLP-32C module.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-29**:
Please update your question with what you've done/attempted so far.

**Comment by [Azergoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34694/azergoo/) on 2018-08-04**:
Have you come any further? I'm interested since I might get a VLP-32.